# Progress calculation in CouchbaseLite.NET

Tags: couchbase-lite

I'm getting some interesting results when using CouchbaseLite.NET's progress events to track replication progress, in that the `CompletedChangesCount` never seems to get up equal to the `ChangesCount` value, with the result that my progress bar never gets to 100%.

Can anyone shed light on this please? Is my calculation too naïve?

TIA